# How to Use the ArrayField in Django to Store a Python List of Strings

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I have read the documentation but I didn't get it. I didn't understand the example code either. I want to store a Python list of strings with ArrayField. Can anyone give me a minimal example of how to store a list with ArrayField?

I have googled the topic but I didn't find any tutorial or other material that addressed my use case.

```
class Sentence(models.Model):
sent = models.CharField(max_length=150)
msg_list = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=500), blank=True, 
            null=True) # This field has errors. 
sent_correct = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Comment: Where **exactly** are you having problems? What code have you used to store the list, and what happened? Setting a list to an arrayfield is no different from setting a string to a charfield, for example.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Actually, I have no idea about the ArrayField. Will it work like a regular list, like, Sentence.msg_list.append(i)?

Comment: Well why don't you try? But not in that case, because Sentence is the class not an instance. Just as you wouldn't do `Sentence.sent = 'whatever'` but `my_sentence.sent = 'whatever'`.

Comment: I think I have asked this question a little early but I am confused. I know that I will need to work on a class instance instead of on the class itself as you have pointed out.